# Impossible to insert text in a FormField that is inside a single cell table

Tags: ms-word, bookmarks, form-fields

I am trying to insert data from an Access Database into a Word document.

I cannot do it using simply Merge functionality, since the information I want to get does not come always from the same database field for a specific word field.

I just wanted to have "placeholders" or fields where I can set text got directly from the database using VBA. Doing it in excel is easy but in Word seems a bit more complicated.

I wanted to have a template where it can be seen where the future information will be written from the DB.

For formatting purposes, we have a single cell table that has some text in it, so that we can easily center that text both vertically and horizontally, center the table relative to the page and give and entire background color, sizing the table as wide as the page.

I put a field inside the table and when I try to set that FormFioelds text i get an error saying that the range cannot be deleted. I think it is error number 6028.
The simple code I use is this:
The FormField is assigned a bookmark name of "title_field".

```
With ThisDocument
    .FormFields("title_field").Range.Text = rs!title
    'Other code here
End With
```

I don't get that error with fields out of the table, that are directly in the document and the text sets ok.

Is the error caused by some rule I should know about?

Answer (score 0):

«*the information I want to get does not come always from the same database field for a specific word field*»

Provided the fields are from the same record, that shouldn't matter. Presumably you have some logic that determines which data field gets output. Field coding in a Word mailmerge main document can be used to determine which data field's output to display. For a demonstration of some of what can be done with mailmerge field coding, see the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** page at:

https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

«*For formatting purposes, we have a single cell table ... and give and entire background color, sizing the table as wide as the page*»

If you're shading the page, whether via page shading or a shaded autoshape in the background, there is no need to apply any shading to the table to have it match the background.

As for your macro code, it works fine for me.